# mootools clone form element

Tags: forms, mootools, clone

I cannot get a form to submit additional fields that have been cloned. When a form like the one below is submitted, it does not include the cloned form elements. Does anybody know why and how I can alleviate this issue.

```
<form>
    <table>
    <tr><td><input type="text" value="50" name="myvar[]" /></td></tr>

    <!-- This button will clone the previous set of form elements -->
    <tr><input type="button" value="Add New Line" onclick="this.getParent('tr').getPrevious('tr').clone().inject(this.getParent('tr'), 'before')" /></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comment but the form was meant to be an example not actually what I had. I looked back at the form and the top form element was inside the table and the bottom form element was outside of the table. I moved the top form element outside of the table and everything works perfectly.

thanks,

Comment: Use "add comment", not posting a new answer, to respond to answers. Delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML isn't well formed, so `this.getParent('tr')` is returning `null` at least for me in Firefox. Put the button inside a `td` that is inside the `tr` and it works.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/delvarworld/r99fN/ clicking the button throws an error